# Group Theory Order Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose *G* is a group, *u* and *v* are elements in *G*, and *u*,*v* satisfy the following: For all *k* $\in$  $\aleph$, $u^{k}$=*e* if and only if $v^{k}$=*e*. Using the definition of order, prove, in a couple of sentences, that |*u*|=|*v*|.

Ok so I know that the definition of order is {min *n* $\in$ $\aleph$: $a^{n}$=*e*, if it exists, infinity otherwise}. But I don't why the relation above makes the orders the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose $\aleph$, in usual language, is simply the set $\mathbf N$ of natural numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(x) = \{ k \in \mathbb N, k\ne 0 : x^k = e \}$. Then

- $|x| = \infty$ iff $A(x) = \emptyset$
- $|x| = \min A(x)$, if $A(x) \ne \emptyset$

The hypothesis in the problem is that $A(u) = A(v)$. That $|u|=|v|$ follows from the key facts above.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|u|=m$ and $|v|=n$. Since $u^m = e$, we have $v^m=e$, so that $n\le m$. Similarly, since $v^n=e$, we have $u^n=e$, so that $m\le n$.

If $u$ has infinite order, then $v$ must as well, since otherwise $v^n = e$ so that $u^n = e$ and then $u$ has finite order. So in this case as well $|u|=|v|$.